# Ubuntu (14.04.02) installation fails on device with NVIDIA GeForce GTX970

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install an Ubuntu/Windows dual boot.

Windows 7 Professional is successfully installed.

I've created a Flash disk with LinuxLive USB Creator and ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso

When I boot my computer to the flash disk, I get a purple screen with two icons at the bottom (A bar and a circle with a five point star (stickman?))

This goes away and a series of messages scroll by.  This runs for 2-3 seconds then stops.  No further progress is made.  When the message scrolling stops the last messages are:

```
[  2.388319]  input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
[  2.388365]  ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[  2.388417]  input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
[  2.388469]  ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[  2.388480]  input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWBN:00/input/inp
```

Every time I try to install the numbers on the left change slightly but the messages always cut off at the same spot.

If I press space at the initial purple screen, I do access the options menu that allows me to select my language (English) and proceed from there, but the result is the same.

Not sure if my hardware is relevant but I have the following:

- Gigabyte Z97X - Gaming 5 motherboard
- Intel i7-4790K CPU
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX970
- Microsoft USB keyboard and Microsoft USB mouse connected.
- Crucial 1 terabyte SSD CT1024M550SSD1

Any ideas what could be causing Ubuntu to fail to launch or install?

Comment: Did you try the "nomodeset" option (F6 ? at the "try"/"install" screen)?  Probably video problems.

Comment: Setting nomodeset has no effect.  Same problem with or without nomodeset checked.  Thanks for the suggestion though. Any others?

Answer (score 1):

Got this working but it was a number of things.

1. Changed Initial GFX display in Bios to be the onboard graphics display of the Intel i7-4790K (This required rewiring my monitor cables too. Forgot that at first)
2. Used `nomodeset` option as [suggested by ubfan1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652972/ubuntu-14-04-02-installation-fails#comment938240_652972) in comments.  I'm not sure if this helped or not. I did not try without `nomodeset`.  Running with the intel onboard graphics instead of the NVidia card was the important factor.
3. If I selected Flash Drive in the boot menu then Ubuntu install would not see my windows installation.  Selecting UEFI Flash Drive in the boot menu made it so that Ubuntu installation would see the Windows installation.
4. After all installing and updating, switched my Inital GFX display in the Bios back to PCI1.  (This was probably not necessary, but did it to be sure my graphics card is being used instead of Intel onboard graphics. Also switched wires back!)